# How to hide the Y Axes in a frame styleplot?

Tags: plotting, legending

For example in the Plot:

```
Plot[ Sin[x], {x, -2, 3}, Frame -> Automatic,  PlotTheme -> "Scientific"]
```

I want to hide the line where `x=0`. Anyone can help?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: try `Axes->False`

Comment: It seems to be inherent in the `PlotTheme -> "Scientific"`, even if you take @kglr's suggestion. Do you really need that option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those "axes" lines are actually coming from the [`GridLines`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GridLines) option. So:

```
Plot[
    Sin[x], {x,-2,3},
    Frame -> Automatic,
    PlotTheme -> "Scientific",
    GridLines -> None
]
```

[image]

Comment: Or `GridLines -> {None, {0}}` to leave the `y == 0` line. However, it seems inconsistent to handle different themes differently (e.g., the "Classic" or "Minimal" themes appear to use `Axes` rather than `GridLines`).

Answer (score 1):

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2, 3}, Frame -> Automatic, Axes -> {True, False}]
```

[image]